# Почему при сортировке данных получаются числа в другом формате?

Tags: python, pandas, сортировка, dataframe, numpy

Имеются данные которые нужно подготовить к объединению с другим блоком данных. Для этого хотелось бы хронологично упорядочить их. Пример исходных данных:

```
df1

          pid  syear                   pgsbil               pgfamstd  \
0            101   1984   [3] Fachhochschulreife   [1] verheiratet zus.   
1            101   1985   [3] Fachhochschulreife   [1] verheiratet zus.   
2            101   1986   [3] Fachhochschulreife   [1] verheiratet zus. 
         ...    ...                      ...                    ... 
6            102   1984  [1] Hauptschulabschluss   [1] verheiratet zus.   
7            102   1985  [1] Hauptschulabschluss   [1] verheiratet zus.   
         ...    ...                      ...                    ... 
484168  31433802   2012   [2] Realschulabschluss   [1] verheiratet zus.   
484169  31433901   2012               [4] Abitur  [2] verheiratet getr.
```

Я пробовал отсортировать используя код:

```
DF1 = df1.sort_values(by='syear', ascending=1)
```

Но вместо года я получаю, по моему мнению, его в другой кодировке (как и всё остальное!):

```
Df1
Out[53]: 
           pid  syear                        pgsbil       pgfamstd  \
248899   320797655 -32656                            81            -95   
248825   891723238 -32419                            43             43   
250014   345587954 -32377                           NaN           -119   
           ...    ...                           ...            ...   
250163   957561202  31108                           -91             27   
250166   449665857  31554                            -1             -1
```

Почему при сортировке данных получаются числа в другом формате? Как мне исправить это?

Comment: укажите пожалуйста вывод (output) след. команд: `df1.syear.min()`, `df.syear.max()` и `df1.dtypes`

Comment: Для команды `df1.syear.agg(['min','max'])` вышла ошибка `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'agg'`
А для второй команды:
pid            int32 /
syear          int16 /
pgsbil      category / 
pgfamstd    category / 
pglabgro       int32 / 
pgemplst    category / 
dtype: object

Comment: да, я уже заметил ошибку и поэтому поправил код в комментарии...

Comment: Странно, на первую команду `df1.syear.min()` я получаю `-32656`, а на вторую нормальные данные `df.syear.max()` результат `2012`.Хотя если я задаю команду `print(max(df1['syear']))`, то получаю 31554.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

похоже у вас в колонке `syear` или действительно отрицательные числа или, что скорее всего, большие положительные (больше 32767), которые при типе данных `np.int16` превращаются в отрицательные...

Демо:

информация о max() и min() для типа `np.int16`:

```
In [67]: np.iinfo(np.int16)
Out[67]: iinfo(min=-32768, max=32767, dtype=int16)
```

как из большого положительного целого (32880) получется отрицательное (-32656) при использовании типа `np.int16`:

```
In [72]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[32880]}, dtype=np.int16)

In [73]: df
Out[73]:
       a
0 -32656
```

неправильные ("плохие") года:

```
In [88]: df1.query('syear <= 1980 or syear > 2016').syear
Out[88]:
248737    -9076
248738   -26593
248739     1725
248740   -25171
248741     7963
248742    27137
248743    19854
248744    26738
248745     6716
248746     9885
248747    19361
248748   -19726
248749   -24605
248750    24074
248751    -8070
248752   -16027
248753   -23424
248754     3848
248755     1471
248756    30634
248757    -8162
248758   -18937
248759    16733
248760   -21923
248761    16817
248762     3834
248763   -13556
248764   -16229
248765    24272
248766    25642
          ...
252510       -1
252511       -1
252512       -1
252513       -1
252514       -1
252515       -1
252516       -1
252517       -1
Name: syear, dtype: int16
```

Интересное наблюдение - все "плохие" данные идут непрерывным блоком (с индексами: 248737 - 252517)

Comment: Хотя пролистав данные, я не увидел ни одного такого значения как 32767 или что-то на это похожее, или отрицательные значения.

Comment: можете выложить куда-нибудь ваши данные в CSV/JSON/HDF5 формате?

Comment: как показать "плохие" данные: `df1.query('syear < 0 or syear > 2016')`

Comment: Я скинул два файла, один исходный, а другой в HDF5. [ссылка](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oa0oggdzyu2m5xz/AABeX51DYq79nT5bhU2R9h8xa?dl=0)
В DropBox

Comment: я проверил: `df1.query('syear <= 1980 or syear > 2016').shape` возвращает: `(3781, 6)` - т.е. в 3781 строке год "плохой"

Comment: Это странно.  Я в программе spyder(python 3.5) сделал тоже самое. и получил такой же результат. Но при просмотре переменных видел что в данной строчке год стоит нормальный. 1997

Comment: В этой программе есть окно, variable explorer, двойным кликом на раздел name или value открывается окно в виде таблицы, прокруткой я дошел до строки 3781, и ней стоял год 1997. И в окрестности данные тоже в порядке. [ссылка](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ju72u257bezcx0/df1.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: я не совсем понятно выразился - я имел в виду что у вас 3781 строка с "плохими" годами. Например в строках: `df1.ix[248737 : 248747, 'syear']`

Comment: Тогда от них придётся избавиться, например котодом который Вы предложили: `df1_clean = df1.query('1950 < syear <= 2012')`

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется это на самом деле такие данные, так как я сортирую по возрастанию, то самые странные такие значения становятся на первое место. Я попробовал команду:

```
syear_counts = df1['syear'].value_counts()
syear_counts
2000     24174
2002     23541
2006     22399
2003     22285
2001     21985
2004     21703
2011     21154
-1         3274
....
-17733        1
 29884        1
 24765        1
-11361        1
```

Скорей всего мне нужно выбросить как-то эту часть данных, которая не репрезентативная. Все строки которые соответствуют таким значениям.

Comment: да, сортировка не могла "испортить" данные. Основной вопрос - как была получена колонка `syear` в  `df1`?

Comment: "выбросить" неправильные данные просто (`df = df[df.syear > 1950]`) - мне кажется стоит разобраться откуда берутся отрицательные года...

Comment: Я загрузил данные `df1 = pd.read_stata('gen_data.dta')`. Похоже половина данных такая. Я заново загрузил данные: `import pandas as pd` -> 
`import os` -> `os.chdir(r'C:\Users\...\SOEPlongv29_stata')` -> `df1 = pd.read_stata('gen_data.dta')` -> ... -> `syear_counts[:10]`
И получил те же самые результаты которые описал выше.

Comment: Я понял как работает эта функция, остаётся проделать тоже самое с верхней границей в 2012 год чтобы выкинуть очень большие данные, вместо года. Такие как: 
`18770        1
 ....
24276        1`

Comment: это как раз не сложно: `df1_clean = df1.query('1950 < syear <= 2012')`